# WFS Layer error

Tags: wfs

I get this error with 1.7.*-Wrowclaw

```
Error downloading http://www.igmi.org/wfs_server?
SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.0.0 - server replied: Bad Request
```

Can I resolve locally or is it necessary work on server?

Answer (score 2):

That looks to be a server error - it is in fact a WMS server not as it's name suggests a WFS server.

On adding it to QGis I can see the layers list but no actual data so it looks to be broken.